# silverstripe internal server error when unpublishin pages

Tags: silverstripe-4

I'm having problems removing pages from a fresh Silverstripe installation (version 4.2.1).

What I'm doing is:

1. Press batch action
2. Select the page I want to remove
3. Choose "Unpublish and archive" in the dropdown
4. Press go button

The result is a popup saying "Internal Server error".

I have tested this on multiple installations with the same error.
It is probably something wrong with my setup (I'm using MAMP 4.5).

But viewing the logs doesn't reveal any problems. I have checked the following logs:

1. apache_error.log
2. mysql_error.log
3. php_error.log

I have also set the `SS_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE = "dev"` in `.env` file.

**Is there somewhere else where I can get a more explaining error message so I can find out what the problem is?**

Comment: I just noticed that I also having problems with publishing a page with "batch actions". But I can publish a page by pressing the "publish" button when the page is open in admin.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Silverstripe: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-admin/issues/579